# Change the cell background color based on the previous 2 columns on Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If the selling rate exceeds buying rate, the selling cell background colour will have green. Make sure Col A & C will have the same products and Col A & B relevant Col. If Col A cells match on Col C cells, then Col D cells will have green based on Col B cells.

I have tried: `=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,$C$1:$C$1000,1,FALSE)))`

But it's not working as i have expected.

[Demo & Expected sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cPiShCU7y1OxtqtHi4fR5RRq3goGn9rFwYQ48or2q1Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you, sir I have added more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well what you need, you can use this conditional formatting:

```
=AND(VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,0)<D2,VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,0)<>"")
```

PS: I've made a copy in F:G

[image]

Comment: But look at little issues, e.g. if Col B is blank, Col G should not fill the background. I have added a new row: 7

Comment: Then try with: `=AND(VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,0)<D2,VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,0)<>"")`

Comment: Perfect, I am reviewing.